# "AttributeError: getZ" error when trying to get the elevation of DXF linestrings

Tags: python, ogr, dxf

I'm using Python and OGR to extract the elevation of lines within a DXF file.

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('DXF')
datasource = driver.Open('test1.dxf', 0)

layers=datasource.ExecuteSQL( "SELECT DISTINCT Layer FROM entities" )
layer=datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)

for i in range(0, layers.GetFeatureCount()):
        layerName = layers.GetFeature(i).GetFieldAsString(0)
        layer.SetAttributeFilter( "Layer='%s'" % layerName)
        print 'Layer=%s|Features=%s' % (layerName, layer.GetFeatureCount())

    for j in range(0, layer.GetFeatureCount()):
      myFeature = layer.GetNextFeature()
      myElevation = myFeature.GetGeometryRef().getZ(0)
```

But I get an "AttributeError: getZ" error when executing it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you would edit your question to include exactly what error you are receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is case sensitive and gdal/ogr doesn't really follow the Python PEP8 [naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). "getZ" is not an ogr.Geometry method, "GetZ" is what you are looking for.

```
>>> help(ogr.Geometry.GetZ)
Help on method GetZ in module osgeo.ogr:

GetZ(self, *args, **kwargs) unbound osgeo.ogr.Geometry method
    GetZ(self, int point = 0) -> double

>>> help(ogr.Geometry.getZ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Geometry' has no attribute 'getZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried with this workaround

```
myGeomRefWkt = myFeature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt()
myElevation = myGeomRefWkt[12:][:-1].split(",")[0].split(" ")[2]
```

to handle the string after "LINESTRING" and between parentheses,`and it works